# Is it advisable to encrypt a RAID device before or after LVM is setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, raid, lvm

I'm currently working on setting up **LVM** on top of a **RAID** device in ubuntu. I'm confused about when to run the encryption (using **cryptsetup** to do this). Should it be;

- after partitioning the drive?
- after creating the raid device?
- or after allocating a logical volume from the LVM volume group?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single correct way to do this.

You would  generally partition then  (software) RAID the disks.

Because I use a number of LVM devices I am inclined to then encrypt the raid device and put LVM on that. There is a bit of setup work with this, but it means that all the lvm partitions can be worked with while only worrying about the passphrase once.